# W10 - How to run a custom CMD from the Context Menu for a specific file

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, context-menu

It's really specific so I'll try to be short.

I want to be able to right click a certain file ending with '.py' (AKA a Python file) and have the option 'Run Python File' that executes the command 'python {FILE NAME}'.

I have seen something similar that works for all files, yet I want to narrow it down to just a specific type of file.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: A similar question on Stack Overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937657/right-click-context-menu-on-windows-executing-python-scripts)

Comment: @spike_66 I know, that was the question I was talking about :)

My problem with it is that it does not have the option to work for just 1 type of file, which is what I am looking for.